# pycel outputs a yaml file with empty cell_map

Tags: python, excel, pycel

#### Code:

```
from pycel import ExcelCompiler

file = 'test.xlsx'
excel_compiler = ExcelCompiler(file)
excel_compiler.to_file(file + ".yaml")
```

#### Outputs:

```yaml
cycles: false
excel_hash: 50c4cf43c7d0ba6fe6ee608b6deebab2
cell_map: {}
filename: test.xlsx
```

Problem is: test.xlsx has `A: 13`, `B: 23` and `C: =A+B`

Why is `cell_map` empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycel does not output an entire spreadsheet.  It outputs the "interesting" parts of a spreadsheet.

### How to indicate the interesting parts of a spreadsheet.

Pycel builds a graph of the cells involved in computations. The graph is built during the process of "compiling" a cell. If the formula for a cell contains references to other cells, those cells are also added to the graph. This process is recursive, and it needs to be seeded with cells of interest, to know which cells to compile.

In the [example](https://github.com/stephenrauch/pycel/blob/master/example/example.py) code, there are at two ways shown to "populate" the calculation graph in pycel.

#### Evaluate a cell, to add it to the calculation graph

```
excel.evaluate('Sheet1!D1')
```

#### Explicitly populate the calculation graph with `trim_graph()`

```
# As an alternative to using evaluate to put cells in the graph and
# as a way to trim down the size of the file to just that needed.
excel.trim_graph(input_addrs=['Sheet1!A1'], output_addrs=['Sheet1!D1'])
```

<sub>Dislaimer: I am the maintainer of Pycel</sub>

Comment: Thank you Stephen kindly take a look at an answer you have provided some months ago:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690629/convert-excel-formula-in-a-cell-to-function-in-a-python-script

What is missing in my case?

Comment: In your example you did not list the exact sheet names and cell addresses. But if your formula is on Sheet 1 in cell C1, then you would need something like `excel.evaluate('Sheet1!C1')`